# Why is the location of files used by a programme off topic?

Tags: support, off-topic, on-topic

I opened [a question](https://superuser.com/questions/840539/) some days ago that has been closed. At this moment the reason given for the closure is:

> the question where FreeCiv files need to go on an Android system is
>   off topic here

Reading [the help page](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), it is not clear why would this be off topic. Moreover, there is [a good number of open questions](https://superuser.com/search?q=where+to+put+files) in this site concerning the location of files used or stored by particular programmes. Why is it ok to ask where wget stores downloaded files and not ok to ask where FreeCiv stores saved games?

Comment: Questions about Android are off-topic, as was stated several times in the comments on your question.

Comment: So why is there an [Android](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/android) tag in this site? And why do you say this question is about Android? It is about a game: FreeCiv.

Answer (score 5):

Subject of the question:

> How to port saved FreeCiv games from Desktop to **Android device**?

Contents, summarized:

> I play FreeCiv on a Desktop computer where I have various games saved. I have recently **acquired an Android device** where I would like to **resume some of these games**

Considering our [Help Page](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask) specially mentions:

> and it is not about …
>   electronic devices, media players, **cell phones or smart phones**, except insofar as they interface with your computer

I'm really not sure why you're continuing to argue about in comments. The [android](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/android) tag exists to ask questions about problems arising due to interfacing an Android phone with a computer.

The tag wiki makes that clear too:

> Unless the device docks with your computer, questions are better on android.stackexchange.com or stackoverflow.com for programming Android applications.

[Android Stack Exchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/) is where you're question is better suited for, since that site pertains to certains specifically on Android

Comment: While I agree it belongs on [Android Stack Exchange](http://android.stackexchange.com/) I worry that they will throw it back to us because he mentions a traditional desktop operating system.  He will need to word the question in such a way that will avoid them doing a migration on him back to Superuser.

Comment: I will repeat the question I made in the original thread: to what phone are you referring to? What is it and how does it relate to FreeCiv? Further, I have no issues interfacing the two systems, either through MTP or through cloud services - this is something one of the users that closed the thread brought up, not me.

Comment: Ramhound: I am pretty sure this question will not be accepted at Android.SE, it would never occur to me to post something like this at that site. In any case, what changes do you see necessary to this question?

Comment: @LuísdeSousa You're asking how to run or where to place the files on your Android phone/tablet/whatever device. So of course you should ask it on [Android.SE]. Especially when you say you have no issues interfacing the systems, which, exclusively, is *the only topic* where Android questions are acceptable for Super User. If you have no issues with the part that would be on topic here, and your issue is about something that is off topic here (because it runs on Android), then **ask it on the Android site, and not here**.